# Rofi custom script on combi mode

Tags: bash

I made a simple custom script to quick open a project on vscode thanks to ghq:

```sh
selection=$(ghq list | rofi -dmenu -p "Project" -no-custom)

[[ ! -z "${selection}" ]] && code ${HOME}/p/${selection}

exit 0
```

I bound it on i3 config:

```
bindsym $mod+d exec --no-startup-id rofi -show combi
bindsym $mod+p exec --no-startup-id ~/.config/rofi/project.sh
```

It works like a charm. Howeverm I want to make it part of the combi mode in order to have only one shortcut.

How can I achieve this?

If this is not possible with rofi, does a similar tool permit that?

Comment: My bash doesn't know what `bindsym` is.

Comment: @Roadowl it's a i3 config command https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#keybindings

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do by adding a script to your rofi config in ~/.config/rofi/config.rasi:

```css
configuration {
    combi-modi: "window,drun,ssh,Project:~/.config/rofi/project.sh";
    modi: "combi";
}
```

Then you need to modify your script, so it will return a list of projects when no arguments are given and open a project when the script is launched with a project name as an argument:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# List projects if no arguments given
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    ghq list
else
    code "$HOME/p/$1"
fi
```

Now, `rofi -show combi` should open with a default combi mode+project launcher.

By the way, I am not sure if the `exit 0` at the end of the script is needed. It makes the script always return successful status, no matter the exit status of used commands. See the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308209/368789).

Comment: It didn't work for me, but this one did:  rofi -show project -modi project:~/project.sh

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was trying a simple file finder script for rofi

At first my attempt was:

```
fd -H . ~ | rofi -dmenu | xargs xdg-open > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Calling the script from the command line works like a charm, but when I tried this inside rofi, didn't work. Of course I can't call rofi indide rofi

Following the idea here, given by Cezary,I got to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    fd -H . ~
else
    xdg-open "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

Turns out, de `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` was important, so it wouldn't freeze the whole thing. Maybe only the "&" in the end is important, so the process goes to the background? The rest, as I understand, just throws away any output or errors.

In my "config.rasi" from rofi, I have the line

```
modi: "drun,Finder:/path/to/script";
```

since I want it as a second mode, instead of a combi. Of course I made it executable with chmod +x.